# Initialise a UITableViewController recursively

Tags: ios, uitableview, recursion

I have a TableViewController called MachinesListViewController that gets loaded when the application starts. 
The data that the tableview shows is a hierarchical tree data so a item has got children, and those children have children and so forth. So first time this loads, it shows the root node.

What I am trying to do is, when a item is selected from the MachinesListViewController I want to create another instance of the same MachinesListViewController so that I can recursively navigate the tree structure.

```
NSDictionary *orgObject = [orgStructure objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MachinesListViewController *m = (MachinesListViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MachineListViewController"];
m.orgId = [orgObject objectForKey:@"id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:m animated:NO];
```

The code works, but I find that the same UITableView is getting updated and the new view controller is not being pushed. It is as though the same instance of the controller is being returned and being changed.

To verify that i am getting different instances of the controller, I debugged the same and printed the memory address of the object. The debugger shows different memory addresses so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

[image: Memory Address]

I am not sure what is going on and any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the data source of the tableView in the new MachinesListViewController set to the new VC?

Comment: Since its a TableViewController, the data source is self. The UI also updates with the information from the chid entires. Its just not getting pushed into the view controller stack.

Comment: Can you try using presentViewController instead of the deprecated push? You can also try to present it on top of the current MachinesListViewController instead of the navigation controller.

Comment: No that doesnt really help me.

Comment: @Sharath You're probably experiencing a different problem. If you have a close look at memory addresses, self is different from m (compare last 4 characters). As per docs, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` ALWAYS returns new instance.

Comment: @JurajBlahunka - Yes. That is the reason I am also stumped as to what is going on..